# Laravel Dependency Injection not working with new Service Provider

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I am currently having some issues setting up some dependency injection for a new service I have made.

I am trying to get `PartyRingService` to inject into a constructor without me passing it in.

I have tried the following in my `PartyRingServiceProvider`:

```
class PartyRingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton('App\Services\PartyRingService', function ($app) {
            return new PartyRingService();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I have added to `config/app.php` my new service provider to the providers array:

```
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */
......
App\Providers\PartyRingServiceProvider::class,
```

And this is the constructor where I am trying to inject my service:

This is the class where I am trying to use my new service in the constructor:

```
class Party
{
    private PartyRingService $partyRingService;

    public function __construct(PartyRingService $partyRingService)
    {
        $this->partyRingService = $partyRingService;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I am getting the following error when I am trying to use `PartyService`:

> ArgumentCountError PHP 8.2.7
> 10.13.5 Too few arguments to function App\Party::__construct(), 0 passed in
> /var/www/html/app/Http/Controllers/PartyController.php on line 28
> and exactly 1 expected

This is what line 28 of `PartyController` looks like:

`$party = new Party();`

I feel like I am just missing a step here, so if someone could help me identify it, that would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use this in your controller:

```php
$party = resolve(Party::class);
```

And that will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure, but shouldn't you add PartyRingService when resolving Party class

```
    {
        $this->app->singleton('App\Party', function ($app) {
            return Party($app->make(PartyRingService::class));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have imported the Party class and the PartyRingService class at the top of your controller file:

```
use App\Party;
use App\Services\PartyRingService;
```

This assumes that the Party class and the PartyRingService class are present in the correct namespace.